# Pulling date of user's last purchase in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, ubercart

So I'm working on a project where I need to pull specifically the last purchase a user has made in ubercart and output the date plus a year on a specific page. I'm pretty lost as to how to go about this, the project was being handled by a coworker who quit and I don't have a whole bunch of drupal experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) AS last_purchase_date FROM uc_orders WHERE uid = YOUR_USER_ID
```